# Randomly generating moving 2D objects that have a direction of movement based on spawn position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, game-engine

I'm currently working on a game in Unity where I want objects to be randomly generated just outside the confines of the touch screen and move according to the side of the screen they are spawned on (Either Left, right, above or below the screen randomly). If they spawn on the left of the screen -> they move to the right onto the screen, if they spawn on the right they move to the left onto the screen, if they spawn from above --> they move down onto the screen ext... I tried doing this by randomly picking a string from an array made up of 4 values (up, down, left, right)and subsequently using a switch statement that will execute different code based on spawn position of the object. The problem is that the code only spawns objects from the down position going up and also for some reason seem to spawn objects at a specific X position close to the middle the majority of the time. Does anyone know why this is the case and how I can solve this problem.

I tried using a random selection method and switch statement that will assign the corresponding vector values according to the particular side of the screen that the object spawns on

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

 public class BallSpawner : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public GameObject BallPrefab;
     public float respawnTime = 1.0f;
     private Vector2 screenBounds;
     private string[] edges = {"up","down","left","right"};
     static System.Random random = new System.Random();
     private float gap = 0.4f;


     // Start is called before the first frame update
     void Start()
     {
         screenBounds = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new           
     Vector2(Screen.width, Screen.height));
         StartCoroutine(BallWave());
     }
     private void spawnBall()
     {
         GameObject a = Instantiate(BallPrefab) as GameObject;

              int r = random.Next(edges.Length);
              string edge = edges[r];
         Vector2 moveVector;


         switch (edge)
         {
             case "up":

                 moveVector =  a.transform.GetComponent<CubeConstantMove>     
            ().moveVector;
                 if (moveVector.y < 0)
                 {
                     a.transform.position = new Vector2(Random.Range(-          
            screenBounds.x, screenBounds.x), screenBounds.y + gap);
                 }
                 break;
             case "down":
                 moveVector = a.transform.GetComponent<CubeConstantMove>     
                 ().moveVector;
                 if (moveVector.y > 0)
                      {
                          a.transform.position = new      
         Vector2(Random.Range(-     screenBounds.x, screenBounds.x), - 
           screenBounds.y - gap);
            }
                 break;
             case "left":

                 moveVector = a.transform.GetComponent<CubeConstantMove>               
         ().moveVector;
                 if (moveVector.y < 0)
                 {
                     a.transform.position = new Vector2(-screenBounds.x - 
  gap, Random.Range(-screenBounds.y, screenBounds.y));
                 }
                 break;
             case "right":

                 moveVector = a.transform.GetComponent<CubeConstantMove>     
             ().moveVector;
                 if (moveVector.y < 0)
                 {
                     a.transform.position = new Vector2(screenBounds.x + 
        gap, Random.Range(-screenBounds.y, screenBounds.y));
                 }
                      break;
                  default:
                 break;
         }



          //*Manipulate to respanw from just outside the confines
     }
     IEnumerator BallWave()
     {
         while (true) {
             yield return new WaitForSeconds(respawnTime);
             spawnBall();
         }
     }
 }
```

The Ball should continuously spawn at a random position along the four sides of the screen and move with a predefined speed to the right onto the screen if spawned to the left, to the left if spawned to the right, down if spawned above the screen, up if spawned below the screen.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYnrz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Of course all your prefabs are going to be spawned at the same position; you don't *specify* a transform.position for them to spawn at. Instantiate takes in *3* arguments (prefab, position, rotation). Since you're only specifying the first argument, it's going to spawn the object at its own transform position. In your case, this is probably (0,0,0) - which is why its spawning at the center of the screen. If you want to confirm it, click on the actual prefab that's inside of your assets folder and look at its transform position - that's the position that your prefab will spawn at by default. Again, if you want it to spawn somewhere else, you have specify *where* in the Instantiate function.